# Which output should I use for prediction with LSTM for sequenced data?

Tags: python, time-series, pytorch, lstm

I'm still new to machine learning and deep learning. I am currently trying to predict time series data with LSTM in PyTorch. The problem I am having is that I don't understand which output should I use for my final prediction.
My code is given below:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, seq_len, dropout):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.dropout = dropout
    self.seq_len = seq_len
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
        input_size = self.input_size,
        hidden_size = self.hidden_size,
        dropout = self.dropout
    )
    self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size)

  def reset_hidden_state(self):
    self.hidden = (
        torch.zeros(1, self.seq_len, self.hidden_size),
        torch.zeros(1, self.seq_len, self.hidden_size)
    )

  def forward(self, sequences):
    lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(sequences, self.hidden)
    y_pred = self.linear(lstm_out[-1, :, :])
    return y_pred

mymodel = Model(5, 10, 1, 3, 0.0)
inps = torch.randn(10, 3, 5)   #input
#print(inps)
mymodel.reset_hidden_state()
out = mymodel.forward(inps)
print(out.shape)
print(out)
```

**output:**

> torch.Size([3, 1])
>
> tensor([[-0.0996],
>           [-0.0587],
>           [-0.0421]], grad_fn=)

As you can see, this gives me three outputs, but my output size is 1 as I am trying to predict only 1 variable. So, in this case which variable should I use for my **final** prediction? Or, is it is even possible to predict only 1 value for sequential data like this?

**NB:** My python version is 3.7.4
and my PyTorch version is 1.4.0

And, sorry if I have made any mistake while asking the question. This is my first time asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the correct output of the LSTM, which is the last hidden state. Conveniently that is also the last element in `lstm_out`, which you are using as `lstm_out[-1, :, :]`.

The input of the model `inps` are multiple sequences, because their size is *[seq_len, batch_size, num_featuers] = [10, 3, 5]*. That means you have 3 independent sequences, which have 10 time steps each with 5 features per time step.

Therefore, the `out` (size: *[3, 1]*) contains the predictions for each of the 3 sequences. `out[0][0]` is the prediction of the first sequence, `out[1][0]` of the second, and `out[2][0]` of the third. You can also get rid of the singular second sequence with `out.unsqueeze(1)`, so you have a 1D tensor with the 3 predictions.

If you want to predict only a single sequence, you would use a batch size of 1, which means the input would have size *[10, 1, 5]* instead, then you get a single value back, even though it's in a tensor of size *[1, 1]*.